# Twig multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, twig

I'm pretty new to Twig. First of all I don't have access to PHP files whatsoever so my question has to be done purely with template variables. I'm using a SaaS platform. And I'm aware that this causes the website to be much slower.

I'm trying to create an array of category names for each level of categories.

So you have a main category. Underneath that level1 subcategories, then level2 subcategories etc...

```
Example:
    - T-shirts (main category)
    - Sweaters (main category)

    - Jeans (main category)
      |-> kids jeans (subcategory)
      |-> woman jeans (subcategory)
        |-> blue (subsubcategory)
        |-> yellow (subsubcategory)
        |-> black (subsubcategory)
            |-> Size L (subsubsubcategory)
            |-> size XL (subsubsubcategory)

      |-> mens jeans (subcategory)
```

What I try to do is to show the categories of the previous level categories when the current category doesn't have subcategories.
So in the example above you see that mens jeans don't have any subcategories.
When opening the category means jeans it should show the categories `t-shirts, sweaters, jeans` in a div somewhere (don't ask me why but client wants that).

Normally I would loop through categories like so:

```
    {% if shop.categories %}

      {% for category in shop.categories %}
      {% if category.subs and category.url is active %}

            <ul class="y">
              {% if category.subs and category.url is active %}
              {% for category in category.subs %}
              <li><a href="{{ category.url | url }}" title="{{ category.title }}" {% if category.url is active %} active{% endif %}">
    {{ category.title }}</a></li>

etc....
```

Now when opening mens jeans the div with subcategories is blank while this category hasn't any subcategories. Therefore the client wants to show the category names from the category above the current category.

The only way I can think of to accomplish this is to create arrays of each level of categories and show them when needed.

So something like:

```
{% set firstLevel %} {{category.name }} {% endset %}
{% set secondLevel %} {{category.name }} {% endset %}
{% set thirdLevel %} {{category.name }} {% endset %}
```

And then:

```
 {% if shop.categories %}

          {% for category in shop.categories %}
          {% if category.subs and category.url is active %}

          {% elseif not category.subs %}
          // show categories before this category
          {{ firstLevel }}

etc...
```

Is this possible? If yes how can I accomplish this? 
I'm pulling my hair out on this one so any help greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE as requested**

The visual outcome should be, example mens jeans:

```
The script/loop should show the main-categories 
because mens jeans doesn't have any subcategories

<div>
- kids jeans
- Women jeans
- <strong>Mens jeans</strong>
</div>
```

The visual outcome of womans jeans should be( they all have subcategories):

```
// I click womans jeans
<div>
- blue
- yellow
- black
</div>

// When I click further, eg "black", then outcome should be:
<div>
- Size L
- Size XL
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Could you provide the expected visual output of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @DarkBee: I've updated my question. For women jeans the loop should stay as it is.

Comment: So you will print the full list with the navigation `and` an extra div, with categories on the same level?

Comment: @DarkBee: I've updated the question again..